# WCF Pass extra security data through all service calls

Tags: wcf, security, wcf-security, wcf-client

Client side I need to pass a piece of information (for this example lets say a string) to every service call I make.  The services use this string (currentRole) along with user/pass credentials to retrieve a user's set of claims associated w/their current role.

The solutions I have come across thus far are:

1) Modify message headers as they go out from the client and verify that the message header is there service side.

2) Use a custom credential which from what I understand requires a custom security token as well to store the string.

Are there any other approaches I a missing such as just adding that info to an existing token/credential?  And are there any pros/cons of the solutions mentioned above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also write a Client-side behavior which would add this header to the messages (so you wouldn't have to think about doing it yourself in your code).

You could implement a `IClientMessageInspector` and in the `BeforeSendRequest` method override, add a message header. When you add this behavior to each of your client endpoints, it'll add that message header automatically to each outgoing message.

See this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37156/Focus-on-the-Extension-of-WCF-Behavior) for some starter infos, and this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx) for some more in-depth know-how.

Marc

Comment: Thank you for your reply that is the approach I took with modifying the message header.  I like it I just wasn't sure if there is any downside to using this approach or if there is something else out there that is more appropriate for this issue.